# SQL Finding all sales orders without using joins

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table Diagram:

[image]

Code output:

[image]

```
Select sod.SalesOrderID, count(sod.OrderQty) as [units]
from SalesLT.SalesOrderDetail sod
Group by SalesOrderID
Having count(sod.OrderQty) > 14
```

I'm trying to find all sales orders containing at least 15 units that can be made up of different products. I'm trying to do this without using Join functions but my code is apparently wrong.

EDIT: wait, am I supposed to be using ProductID instead of SalesOrderID?

Comment: 1) Please **do not** post images, instead post data as formatted text, so others can copy/paste it to test it and brings a solution to you. 2) Why without `JOIN`s? any reason?

Comment: I guess to learn how to do it more than one way.

Comment: If you solved the problem, post your answer. Don't forget as well, however, to ensure your question is a complete question.

Comment: Please don't edit the question such that it no longer makes sense. If you want to show your solution, then add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `sum()`, not `count()`:

```
Select sod.SalesOrderID, sum(sod.OrderQty) as [units]
from SalesLT.SalesOrderDetail sod
Group by SalesOrderID
Having sum(sod.OrderQty) > 14;
```

`count()` simply counts the number of rows, so your version is counting the number of rows for each `SalesOrderID`.

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding on your question, you have to ***Sum*** up the order_qty and display the ***sales_order_id*** if it is more than 14 instead of counting the rows.
Use ***sum*** instead of ***count***

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement isn't completely clear. It's always a good idea to use the same terms to describe your requirement as used in your table and column names.  If you're doing this kind of work for a business person, it's your responsibility as a programmer to recast the requirement in the terms of your database's names. And, it's also your responsibility to check with your customer to make sure you understand.

I guess your requirement is this.

Find the SalesOrderId values of all sales orders containing a total OrderQty of 15 or more units, and also containing two or more different ProductId values.  You'd get that with something like this.

```
SELECT SalesOrderID, 
       SUM(OrderQty) TotalQuantityInOrder,
       COUNT(DISTINCT ProductId) CountOfProductsInOrder
  FROM SalesOrderDetail
 GROUP BY SalesOrderID
HAVING SUM(OrderQty) >= 15 AND COUNT(DISTINCT ProductID) >= 2
```

But, again, I'm guessing  about your requirement.

Answer (score -1):

please check below code:

```
Select sod.SalesOrderID, count(sod.OrderQty) as [units]
from SalesLT.SalesOrderDetail sod
Group by SalesOrderID
Having units > 14
```

Comment: This is the same as the code I posted/tried myself and it gave me the wrong value.